# Why can people only accept one answer on a question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, asking-questions

I recently asked a question which received three good answers. It was my first question and I was surprised to find that it was only possible to accept *one* answer. All three were helpful and did what I wanted to do, and I found it quite difficult to decide which to accept. What are the reasons for people asking a question only being allowed to accept one answer?

Comment: Upvote all the helpful answers. Accept the one that was **most** helpful. That's what the accept means - it is **most** helpful to yourself.

Comment: Note that you don't **have** to accept an answer either. If you cannot pick one, don't pick any?

Comment: If you like all answers then you can up vote all. But accept only which is most helpful.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not sure that choosing to not accept any is really a good action. If they were all helpful then the OP should pick one to accept, IMHO. If the content and timing of all were identical then I would suggest using an arbitrary way of choosing which to accept if need be. Not choosing one, assuming they all were helpful in solving the solution, may make future visitors not bother putting much thought into any of them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok, fair enough and agreed.

Comment: also I don't think that *"whoever answered first"* should be taken into consideration - unless all 3 answers were **exactly the same**...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

StackOverflow (all SE sites actually) uses a Q/A mechanism. There should only be one correct answer to a question, otherwise it'll be "to broad" for SO.

That being said, people are so active on SO that a question can recieve multiple answer telling the same solution. In such a case, it's good to determine which of them will be the most helpfull to others having the same problem. Which answer explains it the best? Which gives the best example? Etc.
If they are all *identical*, people usually accept the first posted answer.

Please note that *not* only an accepted answer is appreciated by the asker. You can accept the best/first answer and upvote all 3 answers.

Answer (score 7):

If each of the three answers contains different, helpful information, consider combining them into one comprehensive answer. This will make the solution easier to find for future visitors. To avoid taking credit for someone else's work, give appropriate attribution and consider marking your super answer as "community wiki."